# Can every path connected $1$-surface in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ be globally parametrized?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, path-connected

Let $f : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth function such that $S:=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is a path connected $1$-surface

( i.e. rank $Df(a)=n , \forall a\in S$ ) .

Then is it true that there exist a smooth function $g: I \to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ such that $g(I)=S$ and rank $Dg(a)=1 , \forall a \in I$ , where $I$ is an open connected subset of real line ?

Comment: Yes, this is true. In fact, any k-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n}$ can be locally parametrised by open sets in $\mathbb R^{k}$

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda : I am asking globally ... not locally

Comment: I am sorry. No this is not true. Take $\mathbb S^{1}$. It is the zero set of a smooth function. But it cannot be parametrised by a connected open subset of a real line, since it is compact.

Comment: @TheveryfluffyPanda : I doubt that ... $g:(-1,1) \to \mathbb R^2$ as $g(t)=(\cos 2\pi t , \sin 2\pi t)$ is a parametrization of $S^1$ . ( note that I don't want my parametrization to be injective ) . ( btw the "compact" ness reason you give is of no use ... it is possible that domain is not compact but range is ... )

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Well I learned something from this question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any one-dimensional connected manifold is diffeomorphic to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$. If $S$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, you can choose $g$ to be a diffeomorphism and if $S$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$, choose a diffeomorphism $h \colon S^1 \rightarrow S$ and compose it with the cover map $\pi \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ to get your $g = h \circ \pi$. It won't be a diffeomorphism but $g(\mathbb{R}) = S$ and $g$ will be an immersion (so $dg$ will be of constant rank one).

Comment: how do you prove that any one-dimensional connected manifold is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or $S^1$ ?

Comment: It requires some work. See the appendix of Milnor's book "Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint" (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnortop.pdf). A different approach is outlined in a set of exercises in John M. Lee's book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".